# How to configure Apache XML-RPC to log to a file instead of the console?

Tags: java

How can I configure Apache XML-RPC to log to a file instead of the console?

EDIT: The project uses commons-logging. I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you had a look at the logger used ? Log4j ? java logging ? SLF4j ? commons-logging ?
Depending on the framework used you will have your answer I guess.

***EDIT:*** based on the [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/guide.html#Configuration) documentation, if you have log4j in your classpath then it will be used. To override any log4j.properties or log4j.xml file that would be in your CP, launch your application with the following JVM parameter

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=path-to-your-log4j.xml
```

Comment: I believe it uses commons-logging, wich I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: then as I have edited, you can configure the real logger using its own configuration. Either it will be log4j or the logger from the jdk, but both are configurable.